# Best filter for locations from onLocationChanged method

Tags: android, maps

We trying to track users location and draw an accurate lines of users - where they were through the whole recording. 
The thing is that we have several  serious difficulties:

1. Cold start. Our users don't have time to wait when the stable satellite  connection will be acquired. during that time we have dramatical **"shoots"** of coordinates up to 20km from users location. Usually this anomaly comes with serious digression of location.getAccuracy > 200, but not all the time.
2. Location in buildings. This type comes as with serious digression of location.getAccuracy = (10-150) as with **"shooting"** of coordinates when exiting the building.
3. Losing some locations on cut offs.:  If we cut off all location.getAccuracy > 50, we will lose some "good" locations. Furthermore, in some cases  location.getAccuracy was **less than** in **"shooting"** locations.

We started to cut all locations, if their speed was more than 16,7 km/hour, but sometimes "shooting" locations have good speeds because of lag between fixes.

```
private  boolean isPossibleSpeed(Location masterLocation, Location testedLocation){
    double maxPossibleSpeed = 16.7;
    double currentSpeed = (masterLocation.distanceTo(testedLocation)) /
            (masterLocation.getTime() - testedLocation.getTime());
    LogUtil.log("CSB", currentSpeed + "/");
    if (currentSpeed<maxPossibleSpeed){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the pic of the **cold start.** One dote shooted.

http://postimg.org/image/tn43nf0k9/

Any suggestions how to improve recording? Does anybody faced the same issue? I'm sure that there are some good algorithms that can handle this in **REAL TIME.** 
Thanks.